# What is the accuracy of the Kinect sensor?

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How accurate is the depth map of the Kinect sensor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9344/what-is-the-accuracy-of-the-kinect-sensor?/) by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The accuracy regresses quadratically with the distance measurement. [This wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect/kinect_accuracy) gives more information.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on 2011-03-10**:
Thanks for the catch!  I updated the graph.

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-03-10**:
Aren't the axes on the graph on this wiki page reversed? That is, it should plot error vs distance, not distance vs error. Plus the units seem more appropriate to that anyway: meters on the x axis for distance and cm on the y axis for errors.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ultimate accuracy is going to be determined by the range resolution. The range resolution for triangulation based range sensing is given by:

delta_r = r^2/b*K_d

Where r is range, b is baseline, K_d is some constant based on the disparity resolution (focal length * disparity resolution for standard stereo).

I did some tests today and found that for our Kinect, using delta_r = r^2*0.0075 works pretty well.

---

Originally posted by [Nick H](https://answers.ros.org/users/152/nick-h/) with karma: 214 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1